# C#, how to make an increment of int declared as object?

Tags: c#, .net, types, casting

I have an external system which gives me an object value (I know that this value always a boxed integer type). I would like to increment it in the usual way: `int value += otherIntValue`, but I get an error from the compiler:

> Operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type

For example:

```
//source values i cannot to change it
object targetInt = 100;
int incrementedValue = 20;

//usual way - not works
targetInt += incrementedValue;    

//ugly workaround
targetInt = ((int) targetInt) + incrementedValue;
```

Is there a way to increment instances of int and object with `targetInt += incrementedValue;`?

Comment: You already have the solution.

Comment: Why is that 'workaround' (also known as casting) ugly? It seems like an idiomatic way to get an `object` back to an `int`.

Comment: Your example isn't really all that shorter, anyway. What's ugly about an explicit, readable, proper, cast?

Comment: How is your code ugly?

Comment: Increment operation developed for adding to already existed values, why i cannot use it?

Comment: That looks fine, it's explicitly confirming that you know the object is an int. If you do several operations, cast once to an int and use that.

Comment: Think about it this way, YOU know it is always a boxed int, but how does the code know that?  You have to unbox it (a simple explicit cast in this case) so that the code knows to treat the object as an int.

Comment: You could add a property of type `int` that forwards to the `object`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just don't change your code. It's perfectly fine to cast your `object` to an integer so it is possible to make the addition with another integer.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the hell of it, here's a way to do it via operator overloading. You must really hate the casting operator...

```
targetInt += (Int)incrementedValue;

public class Int
{
    private int _value;

    public Int(int value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator Int(int value)
    {
        return new Int(value);
    }

    public static object operator +(object target, Int increment)
    {
        return increment._value + (int)target;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, casting is the correct way to handle a type that is being treated as `object`.

However, that being said, if you *really* want to use arbitrary operators and methods without compile-time type checking, you can use the `dynamic` keyword:

```
dynamic targetInt = 100;
int incrementedValue = 20;

targetInt += incrementedValue;
```